# package chemnum incompatible with [T1]{fontenc}?

Tags: font-encodings, chemnum

If I use the fontenc package, I do not see compound numbers in the scheme:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum}
%\setchemnum{replace-style=,format=}

\begin{document}
\replacecmpd{a}
\replacecmpd{b}
\includegraphics{test.eps}

See compound \cmpd{a} and \cmpd{b}.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If I comment out the fontenc package, it seems to work:

[image]

Comment: Well, without `test.eps` it's impossible to say.

Comment: The `chemnum` manual is compiled with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`… do you really get yellow background behind the numbers?

Comment: sorry no the yellow background is my own emphasis (made with greenshot)

Comment: ChemDraw and eps files: http://dropcanvas.com/i56ly (temporary I guess). The eps file I created by saving as *.eps from ChemDraw.

Comment: @Zalumon your example compiles fine for me and all numbers are there…

Comment: @clemens tnx a lot for testing... that's unfortunate, as it means I have to go hunt in my texstudio settings (maybe it's because I use output-directory). Edit: no, removing the output-dir setting didn't help.

Comment: Do you have the cm-super fonts installed?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it didn't look like I did, meaning it was possible to select it in the package manager and install it (which I now just did). Unfortunately that didn't help :/

Comment: Are the fonts used? (See at the end of a pdflatex compilation).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am still struggling to verify that cm-super is installed and used. I don't really see the package on the file system and I also don't know what to look for in the output. I assume you mean the log file.

Comment: Make a small example with [T1]{fontenc}, compile with pdflatex and then look in the log file which fonts mentioned at the end (`.pk`: bad, `.pfb`: good)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer doesn't look good: MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi600\ecrm1000.pk (took me so long to investigate because the log line was hard-wrapped right between the 'p' and the 'k', so my search always came up empty for both .pk and .pfb)

Comment: btw, I did find the cm-super files: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\type1\public\cm-super (> 400 files, ~60MB)

Comment: Run on a command line `updmap`.

Comment: wow. now I get: <C:/Progra
m Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb>. And the chemnum issue is resolved as well. Thank you very very much! This cost me my whole sunday. Pls convert to an answer and i'll be happy to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the discussion in comments the source of the problem was that the cm-super fonts were not installed and so bitmap fonts were used.

In miktex the fonts can be installed with the package manager. In some installations it is necessary to run the command `updmap` after the installation to update the user map files.