# Chemnum makes the temporary markers TMP disappear but doesn't replace them

Tags: chemnum

This question follows one I posted earlier this week [(here)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353614/chemnum-compounds-numbers-dont-replace-tmp-at-the-right-position-in-eps-file/353631).

I'm having trouble using chemnum, for replacement of temporary labels (TMP1, TMP2, TMP3) in a scheme made with chemdraw. It indeed affects the labels, as they disappear, but they are not replaced at all.

Here is the code I use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,notitlepage]{book}


%Packages
\RequirePackage{etex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{psfrag}

%chemistry packages
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{chemscheme}
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{titlesec}    %to correct spacing of chapters
        \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{20pt}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{1em}{}



%Title
\title{Partie expérimentale}
\author{Me}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Partie Expérimentale}
\section{Synthèse du thiéno[3,2-b]thiophène-2,5-diylbis((3-bromothiophèn-2-yl)méthanol)}


\cmpd*{a}
\cmpd*{b}
\cmpd*{c}

\begin{scheme}[ht]
   \replacecmpd{a}
    \replacecmpd{b}
    \replacecmpd{c}

        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Schema_Synthese_3.eps}


                \caption{Schéma réactionnel 1}

\end{scheme}


\end{document}
```

Here is the result: [image]

And here is the [.eps file](https://www.sendspace.com/file/7m8ow2) if needed.

Any piece of advice on how to get the labels I want?

Comment: Hi, but you could use also `Ipe` rather than use `\psfrag`. With Ipe  you can change, quickly, the labels. See at the link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354244/tracing-with-xfig-to-make-shapepar-command/354332#354332 my answer.

Comment: If I got it right, this is a program to to change the labels? Or is there a way to use it instead of `\psfrag`right in TeXnic Center ?

Comment: At this moment I have not installed TeXnicCenter because I'm using, now, Papeeria or Overleaf. They are two online editors. Personally I have not use `\psfrag`, almost 13 years. For example with, Ipe, InkScape, Adobe Illustator, you can edit easily your labels of your file .eps. You can see too this link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311912/psfrag-does-not-change-the-text or others.

Comment: My point is, I'd rather carry on using TexNic Center, as I'm more accustomed to it.

Comment: @Sebastiano so Ipe can replace arbitrary text markers in an EPS file with arbitrary LaTeX code on the fly from within the LaTeX file? Because that is what `chemnum` uses `psfrag` for. (Loading `psfrag` in addition to `chemnum` is superfluous…)

Comment: @clemens I use Adobe Illustrator to replace arbitrary text markers in an EPS file with arbitrary LaTeX code. I have download i font computer modern .ttf and paste to folder Fonts on W10. With Ipe I have try twice to add labels into file .eps with the LaTeX fonts.

Comment: @Sebastiano so this is a manual solution and nothing I could add to `chemnum`. That's all I wanted to know…

Comment: @clemens Never I have used `chemnum` but `psfrag`. In these days I am very busy to see `chemnum` package. I would not know what to answer you. I simply wrote that there are other ways to put labels in LateX.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem came from the fact that `cm-super fonts` were not installed and so bitmap fonts were used. The answer was found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276022/package-chemnum-incompatible-with-t1fontenc)